# Verification of proof that NM is a normal subgroup of G if M and N are both normal subgroups of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

My proof is as follows: 
M is a subgroup of G means $g_1mg_1^{-1}$ is part of M and likewise N is a subgroup of G means $g_2mg_2^{-1}$.  To prove our claim do the following:

$$g_1mg_1^{-1} g_2ng_2^{-1}$$
$$g_1mg_2g_1^{-1} ng_2^{-1}$$
$$g_1g_2nmg_1^{-1} g_2^{-1}$$ so this is in NM

Is this correct?  If not, what is needed to be changed?

Comment: Start with any $g\in G$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have proved that $NM$ is a subgroup of $G$.To show normal notice

for any $g\in G ,  gNMg^{-1}=\left(gNg^{-1}\right)\left(gMg^{-1}\right)\subseteq NM$ as both $N,M $ are normal in $G$